# While cloning an Active Contract Record, ActivatedDate and ActivatedBy is not stamping correctly

Tags: apex, clone, contracts

For my requirement, I am able to clone an Active Contract but while cloning, The System Fields like Contract Activated Date and Contract Activated by is simply taking my user id values and not of the old record from which it was cloned. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```apex
for(Contract duplicateContract : lstContract) {
    Contract clonedRecord = duplicateContract.clone(false, true, true, true);
    clonedRecord.AccountId = targetAccount.Id;                
}                           
lstContractsInsert.add(clonedRecord);
```

Comment: Please include the code you use for cloning by making an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Here is the code:

for(Contract duplicateContract : lstContract) { Contract clonedRecord = duplicateContract.clone(false, true, true, true); clonedRecord.AccountId = targetAccount.Id;

                        }                           
                        
                        lstContractsInsert.add(clonedRecord);

                    }

Answer (score 0):

The [SFDC Object documentation for Contract](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contract.htm?q=contract) states:

> Client applications must initially create a Contract in a non-Activated state. Client applications can subsequently activate a Contract by updating it and setting the value in its Status field to Activated; however, the Status field is the only field you can update when activating the Contract.

- `ActivatedById` is the running user that activates the Contract (i.e., the user that did the clone)
- `ActivatedDate` is time when the `Contract.Status` went to an "activated value"

per the doc, these fields can be updated using explicit field assignment from the clone source SObject (i.e. `clone` is not sufficient)

Comment: We had to do some modifications after an activated contract is re-inserted and hence we went for approach mentioned in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116291/change-the-account-name-of-a-contract-that-is-activated
and almost successful in cloning the contract. However, When we are cloning it, the Activated Date and Activated By is taking directly from the user who is doing this action Even if I try to assign values from the original record , it is simply not updatable. I also created the permission set mentioned above . Any ideas how to implement this?